# How to debug CUDA code on TCC enabled device on a remote server?

Tags: cuda, nsight

I would like to start a remote debugging session from my development pc on our soon-to-be production server. On the server I start NSight using the remote desktop, and then I try to Start CUDA Debugging on my local machine (given the server as target before). The result is, that the debug session disconnects saying "The remote system is logged in through remote desktop. WDDM adapters will not be debuggable".

Is this intended behaviour,  a bug, wrong configuration? And if there is no solution involveing remote desktop, how could I start the NSight monitor, so that I can start a debugging session?

On the target server I have two Tesla K10 and a Quadro FX (for Display). All Tesla devices (which are actually four), show TCC turned on.

I am using NSight 3.0, CUDA 5.0 and Visual Studio 2008 (the latter two only on the development workstation).

One last thing: Copying the application to the server and executing through remote desktop works fine.

Comment: In the Nsight Connections tool bar if you set the Connection to your server and execute the menu command Nsight | Windows | System Information does the system information page show the 2 K10s as being in TCC mode? I will verify with the Nsight CUDA debugger team that this configuration is supported. I have used this configuration on past versions. In the meantime you can use VNC instead of remote desktop.

Comment: Yes, it shows the devices in TCC mode. But it actually shows 4 devices, as we have two physial cards in the server, and each card contains two GK104 subsystems (as I understand it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you refer to is a warning to let users know that Nsight has detected that you have a RDP session running on the target side and that it won't be able to do Nsight debugging on any WDDM cards in it, if there is one (or more) - which looks like you do, with that Quadro FX that you mentioned).
This message is a Warning, and it should continue to let you run or debug the application under Nsight and debug the application assuming GPU code runs on the TCC devices.  Are you sure the application ran successfully on the target machine?  Can you double check that you have set a GPU breakpoint and see if you hit those breakpoint(s)?
Are there any other messages shown? - you can check the VS Output window.

Which driver version are you using?

Can you try running (double clicking) the application on the server but from the directory that Nsight synced the application to?  It should be under `%appdata\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight\Monitor\Mirror\<hostdev_machine_name>\<path_to_the_sync_app>`
I know you mentioned you tried copying it, but I'd like to see if everything that Nsight sync is what's required by the application and that maybe there's not something missing that you need to specify to sync (more info on syncing is here:  http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Synchronization.htm)

Thank you

Comment: Hi, you are absolutly correct. I tried to execute a little test program, with only a few dependencies and it worked. (The test program actually enumerates the devices and executes a little test kernel, and it only showed the TCC-enabled devices).



Driver is 307.32

Comment: The application I want to debug, is working in the sync directory, but when started remotely it seems to do something and the output window (console) disappears very fast, (I missed that yesterday), but it never reaches the first line of the first kernel. Is there a way to keep this window open, or reach the output?

Comment: Hi Georg, maybe you can you try adding a getchar() to the app and that way it will wait for keyboard input and you can see the console output.

Comment: Hi Georg, one more thing, can you please specifically set the working directory in the "Nexus User properties" (right click on your VS project)? Go under the Launch node and set the "Working directory" to the directory you expect it to run from.  By default (if blank), Nsight sets your working directory to where the .vc[x]proj is located.  Let me know if any of this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. The getchar() was the hint, which helped me the most. Sometimes one doesn´t see the wood for the trees ...

It works now as expected, and I can tackle the actual problem (which looks to be kind of easy, as it is in my application logic).